# Image galleries with <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a website, and I need to 'implement' a gallery on a group of photos. Since I'm using Spring MVC, my images are with 'img src..' tag and regular js and jquery addons don't work. Is there any plugin/library that can help me do this? If not, suggestions for making my way around it are also welcome. Here is the html, if it can somehow help.

```
<div id="img-slider">

                <img class="slider-img" src="/LBProperties/img/bisc.jpg"/>
                <img class="slider-img" src="/LBProperties/img/bisc1.jpg"/>

</div>
```

Thank you !

Comment: _"regular js and jquery addons don't work"_ ? Why ?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide all of the images with CSS:

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
```

Get handlers to the images:

```
var slider = document.querySelector('#img-slider');
var images = slider.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Set an index to 0:

```
var index = 0;
```

Then show the first image:

```
images[index].style.display = 'block';
```

Add a button to your HTML:

```
<div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Get it with script and add a click handler:

```
var button = document.querySelector('#next');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (var ix = 0; ix < images.length; ix++) {
    images[ix].style.display = 'none';
  }

  index++;
  if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
  images[index].style.display = 'block';
});
```

The click handler loops through the images and hides them, increases the index, checks to make sure the index didn't go over the number of images (reset it to 0 if it does), then shows the next image.

Putting it all together:

https://jsfiddle.net/subterrane/osszqoLe/

Comment: Good one Will.. Would be easier with `jQuery`

Comment: I dunno. Typing 'document.querySelector' instead of '$' isn't too terribly difficult. ;) [I'm being intentionally obtuse.]

I think you might be right if you're familiar with jQuery. If I recall, there's lots of shortcuts to manipulating collections without having to loop through them.